# Specify for constructor class fixed values and other variables from container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

What I have is a stage, some interfaces, and also registration section. The problem is I need to defined some parameters as fixed and others as variables.

```
interface IDoSomething {
 void DoWork();
}

interface IDoMath(){
 void DoWork();
}

interface IBehaviorBusiness{
 void Do();
}

class BehaviorBusiness {
 ...
 public BehaviorBusiness(IDoSomething doSomething, IDoMatch doMatch, string connection){};
 ...
}
```

Is it possible with windsor container to define a parameter connection in declaration, and take `IDosomething`  and `IDoMatch` from the container?

```
 container.Register(
   Component.For<IDoSomething>()
   ...
 }

 container.Register(
   Component.For<IDoMatch>()
   ...
 );
```

That is the concrete problem.

```
 container.Register(
   Component.For<IBehaviorBusiness>()
   .ImplementedBy<BehaviorBusiness>()
   .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IDoSomething, [default]>(),
              Dependency.OnComponent<IDoMatch, [default]>(),
              Dependency.OnValue("connection", connectionString))
    .LifeStyle.Transient
   );
```

Which is correct syntax if it exists?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk answer is right but I think a better approach is to make IConnectionString provider or directly IConnectionProvider and serve it in the ctor rather than a direct parameter. This way the particular class will not have the responsibility to create/manage/dispose the connection every time. What about providing the connection from another component and then pool it rather then dispose it? This way you will keep the SRP not just for the sake of keeping some principles but for the maintanability of your code. 
Can you give an example of the usage of your connection string?

Comment: well the project is really small and simple. you are right. finally i changed connection for a dummy interface for query, update     public interface IDbContext
    {
        DataSet GetDataSet(string strmSql);
        DataTable GetDataTable(string strmSql);
        int ExecuteSql(string strmSql);

    } some really simple

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov where can i read about best practices for implements IConnectionString o IConnectionProvider? the next week are working in some really serious and maybe read a little about the topic it would be appropriate. Iam considering use EF or NHibernate

Comment: There are no best practices about this. This is a simple interface with a simple implementation. In your implementation you must put the logic of constructing the connection that you would otherwise spread and multiply across other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection string comes from your application settings, then use [`Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue()`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-dependencies.ashx#appSettings_dependencies:_DependencyOnAppSettingsValue__3):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IBehaviorBusiness>()
    .ImplementedBy<BehaviorBusiness>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue("connection", "connectionString"))
    .LifeStyle.Transient
);
```

Here, "connection" is the name of the parameter in the class' constructor, and "connectionString" is the key of your connection string value in your application settings (i.e. Web.Config).  You don't need to specify the other values, Windsor will resolve them as it usually does.